# Split a text file using delimiter \t and store in hashmap in java

Tags: java, split, hashmap, delimiter

I have a text file of n columns and n rows separated by tab space.. How do i use split function to store the columns and rows into a hashmap.Please help.
My text file will be like..

Dept  Id     Name    Contact
IT    1             zzz       678

ECE   2            ttt       789

IT    3             rrr       908

I tried the following.But it dint work.

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
while(lineReader!=null)
{
String[] tokens = lineReader.split("\\t");
key = tokens[0];
values = tokens[1];
map.put(key , values );
System.out.println("ID:"+map.get(key ));
System.out.println("Other Column Values:"+map.get(values ));
}
```

This returns the key of the last entry(row) of the file and value as null. But i need to store all rows and columns in the map. How do i do it?

Comment: You did not specify what is error you have faced? before that, Create your Hashmap outside the loop. As of now, it creates a hashmap each time the loop runs.

Comment: Yeah have declared it outside the loop. and have specified the error. If i run the code, it gives, ID: 3 (which is the last row in the file) and.. Other Column Values:Null

Comment: A hash map can only have a key and its value. Here you are having 4 columns. Which column is your key and which columns should be the values?

Comment: What is `lineReader` and where it gets its values?

Comment: Your keys must be unique or else they will overwrite previous entries.    Also, how do you expect `map.get(values)` to work?  You can only call `get` using a key.

Comment: @Sanjeev: 2nd column is the key and the remaining column are the values. first column wil be processed further in the program.. not for this requirement.

Comment: @PM77-1: LineReader is just used for reading the file using bufferedreader..I just skipped including those lines of code here..

Comment: @Aurand:Yeah..got it..Could u plz tel me hw to retrieve the values of other columns?

Comment: I don't like to do this @user2376600 but I think you should first read this: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=369 Or something similar.

Comment: @user2376600 - My point is that if the code you show us is actually **inside another loop** and you want to place all data from your file into a single `Collection` (`HashMap` or other), then you need to move creation of such Collection object outside the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data correctly,

After

```
String[] tokens = lineReader.split("\\t");
```

is processed on the first line, you'd have 4 tokens in the array.

I think you are using wrong logic, if you want to store the map in the following way:

IT -> (1 ZZZ 678)
.... etc then you need to process the data differently.

What you are storing in the map is follows:
IT -> 1
ECE -> 2
...
and so on.

That's why you get null when you are trying to do:

```
map.get(value);
```

What you should instead print is the *Key* and *map.get(key)*.

Actually, in any case I don't think Map is what you want (but I don't know what you really want).

For now though, for your understanding of this problem try printing:

```
System.out.println("Total collumns: "+ tokens.length);
```

**Updated:**

This should work for you. It isn't the most elegant implementation for what you want, but gets the job done. You should try improving it from here on.

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
while(lineReader!=null)
{
String[] tokens = lineReader.split("\\t");
key = tokens[1];
values = tokens[2]+tokens[3];
map.put(key , values );
System.out.println("ID:"+key);
System.out.println("Other Column Values:"+map.get(key));
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: As of now, I need to store.. 1,2,3 as key and the respective values of those keys as values to the map... the group IT is to be avoided for the current requirement.

Comment: I have 5 columns in my text file and it prints the length as 6.

Comment: Okay, you never mentioned that in the question. Next time onward try to frame the question clearly. Please see if my updated answer is any helpful.

Comment: May be there are additional "tabbed spaces"? Try printing just the tokens as follows: String[] tokens = lineReader.split("\\t"); for(String token: tokens) System.out.println(token);

Comment: Yeah..Thank you.. :-) its 50% working .. It takes up only the last entry in the text file ..Why is it so? Also, values = tokens[1]+tokens[2]+tokens[3]+tokens[4];> giving this doesnt takes my last column.. If i add tokens[5], it throws exception.

Comment: Ur updated one works.. Thanks a lot..Could you plz help me out in  adding all the rows into the map? To be more clear, each row into each map..(As per my requirement)..

Comment: That's the best I can help with the amount of information I have from you. But I suggest you try on your own.